# Mongoose document.save() throwing "validation failed"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to run a batch update inside my collection using the following code:

```
updateRecordsToDateType = (req, res) => {

    MyModel
        .find({ enabled: true })
        .exec()
        .then( results => {

            results.forEach( result => {
                result.rate= result.rate * 0.98;
                result.lastUpdate = moment();
                result.save()
            });

            res.status(204).end();

        }).catch( error => {
            console.error(error);
        });

}
```

But it's throwing the following error after passing the "result.save()" line:

```
ValidationError {errors: Object, _message: "MyModelvalidation failed", message: "MyModelvalidation failed: _id: Cast to Objec…", name: "ValidationError", stack: "ValidationError: MyModelvalidation failed: _…"}

Cast to ObjectId failed for value "ObjectId("5bc4cf560bef473414cb22ec")" at path "_id"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of updating the documents, you are loading the whole `MyModel` collection into memory. Before you can edit `result` in memory you need to call .toJSON() on it. This is very expensive. You can use [updateMany](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateMany) and use the [$mul](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/mul/) (multiplication) operator to tell the database to do all the work.

```
MyModel.updateMany(
    { enabled: true },
    {
        lastUpdate: moment(),
        $mul: { "result.rate": 0.98 }
    }).then(result => {
        // 
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `forEach` function, you have the line that reads `result.save()`. The reason that this is failing is because `result` is not a model so you cannot save it to the database. What you need to do is create a new model for the single result, save a value to one of the elements of that model, and then save it to the database, something like:

```
let resultModel = new Model();
result.rate= result.rate * 0.98;
result.lastUpdate = moment();
result.save()
```